# Intercepting mouse wheel events of a QListWidget with scrollbars

Tags: qt, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I have a `QListWidget` with some content and active scrollbars. I want to receive its wheel events ahead of it, so that I can do some stuff as needed. I tried implementing `eventFilter` and installing it on the said `QListWidget`, but to no avail: I only receive the desired event if it wasn't consumed by the scroll area, i. e., if it is already scrolled to its limit in the direction of mouse wheel rotation.

Did I do something wrong? Or should I do something else to intercept events properly?

Comment: You can try reimplement QApplication::notify method, because before any event from system to QObject will achieve, it will become to this method. Also QEvent::spontaneous tell you, that this event become from Operation System.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right, you just need to inherit some class from QListWidget and implement wheelEvent handler like that:

```
class EListWidget : public QListWidget
{
public:
    EListWidget(QWidget *parent);

private:
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event);
};
```

...

```
void EListWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    // to do any processing here if you want to do something before scrolling

    // call base implementation
    QListWidget::wheelEvent(event);

   // to do some processing after scrolling.
}
```

Be careful with event->isAccepted() state.

Also you can connect to scrollbars (QAbstractSlider) slot:

> void QAbstractSlider::sliderMoved ( int value ) [signal] This signal
>   is emitted when sliderDown is true and the slider moves. This usually
>   happens when the user is dragging the slider. The value is the new
>   slider position. This signal is emitted even when tracking is turned
>   off. See also setTracking(), valueChanged(), isSliderDown(),
>   sliderPressed(), and sliderReleased().